# Who is this character in Super Smash Brothers Brawl?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

In Brawl there are special items that look like white domes that activate when you pick them up, summoning a character from another game to fight for you for a short time, sort of like Pokemon.

Is there a list of these, what games they are from, and what their abilities are?

In particular, I'm interested in the background of one that shoots out a large green hand horizontally, which can push players off the level.  What universe is this character from, what's his name, etc.?

Comment: Why are they always 26 characters? *Why are game titles always exactly 26 characters long?!*

Comment: Do you have any proof for this claim @Grace?

Comment: @Ivo I had a list earlier. Off the top of my head, "Scott Pilgrim Vs The World" and "Duel of the Planeswalkers", as well as "Mukashi Mukashi aru Tokoro", "Metroid Prime 3 Corruption", "Need For Speed Most Wanted", "Undefined Fantastic Object"... It'd be a lot less aggravating if titles just were plain too long at like 30+ characters.

Comment: Horizon Chase Turbo is a long title with only 17 if I counted right.  It also has the same amount of syllables as Duel of the Planeswalkers.  Just thought I'd mention.

Comment: and Need For Speed Most Wanted.

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with the alphabet having 26 characters?  Maybe that makes it look good visually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are called "assist trophies". There's a list of the ones in SSBB here: http://www.serebii.net/ssbb/assist.shtml

The one you're asking about specifically is Isaac from [Golden Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Sun_(series)).

Answer (score 9):

There is an in-game list of these, but that one you have to build yourself. The "Trophies" you collect in-game, they can be sorted in a method that groups all of the Assist Trophies together. It includes descriptions of who the character is, some minor points on their abilities in-game, and also includes one or more games which they were present in.

You can find an online listing on the official Super Smash Brothers Website [over here](http://www.smashbros.com/en_us/items/assist/index.html). Saves you the time of collecting trophies, naturally.

As mentioned by [Chad Birch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/who-is-this-character-in-super-smash-brothers-brawl/11110#11110), the character in question is Isaac from Golden Sun.

Answer (score -2):

There is also an in-game list of these **assist trophy** characters after you complete either all-star mode or classic mode, though briefly showing those that you have unlocked.